# How do I resolve this include error? The gdk file is where it is supposed to be

Tags: compiler-errors, include, gtk3

I am working on making a GUI for my brothers encryption program. The biggest hangup consists of 2 includes. #include <gtk/gtk.h> and #include <gtk/gtkx.h>. After putting my code into Apache NetBeans, it provides the error "There are unresolved includes in <gtk/gtk.h>" and the same for gtkx.h. After some digging I found that the #include it is referring to is #include <gdk.h> which is within each of the two .h files that have errors.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <gtk/gtkx.h>
#include <gdk/gdk.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <driver.hpp>
#include <decrypt_util.hpp>
#include <encrypt_util.hpp>
#include <util.hpp>

GtkWidget     *window1;
GtkWidget     *fixed1;
GtkWidget     *label1;
GtkWidget     *button1;
GtkWidget     *decryptbt;
GtkBuilder    *builder;





int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

  gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

  builder = gtk_builder_new_from_file ("Attempt.glade");
  //Connects glade file with C++ code
  window1 = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "window1"));
  //Creates pop up window, window is defined as a widget.
  g_signal_connect(window1, "destroy", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);
  //Makes the window x stop the program from running further
  gtk_builder_connect_signals(builder, NULL);
  //Connects signals from gui to code, on button clicked and GetCommandLineA

  fixed1 = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "fixed1"));
  button1 = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "button1"));
  decryptbt = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "decryptbt"));
  label1 = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "label1"));

  gtk_widget_show(window1);

  gtk_main();

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

void on_button1_clicked (GtkButton *b){
  gtk_label_set_text (GTK_LABEL(label1), (const gchar* ) "Hello World");
}
```

The error

```
There are unresolved includes inside <gtk/gtk.h>.
For extra info hold Ctrl and move mouse over include directive
```

Comment: That error very clearly comes from a graphical IDE, not directly from your compiler. So, the info which IDE you're using is kind of important. Probably it's just not aware of all include paths, so it can't know where to take the files from that are included in `gtk/gtk.h`.

Answer (score 0):

That error very clearly comes from a graphical IDE, not directly from your compiler. So, the info which IDE you're using is kind of important. Probably it's just not aware of all include paths, so it can't know where to take the files from that are included in `gtk/gtk.h`. Not a compiler error itself, and not per se a problem. You'll need to check the actual compiler output.

Comment: So essentially, I need to setup a path in the ide i'm using?

Comment: possibly? really, it's not clear whether this is a problem or not at all.